# Don't load page yet until data are all retrieved from the service

Tags: angular

I am trying to display a simple data to the browser in Angular but I want to display the data once ALL data is retrieved from the service.

How to do that?

Currently the page will display even without finishing fetching my data.

Here is sample codes

```
In test.component.ts file

ngOnInit() {
    this._service.getQuestions().subscribe(data => { this.questionCollection = data });
}
```

In my Service

```
getQuestions() {
    return this._http.get('assets/questions.json')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

.html file

```
<div> Other text here...... </div>
<div *ngFor="let col of questionCollection">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">{{col.Text}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? The route not to load, or a loading indicator to be displayed, or the list not to be shown? Showing more of the component code may help, too

Comment: If you want to prevent the navigation from happening until the data is retrieved, you can do so using an auth guard returning an observable.

Answer (score 5):

Angular2 provides AsyncPipe which you can use. As the doc says:

> The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the
>   latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async
>   pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component
>   gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid
>   potential memory leaks.

Read the documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html).

OR - You can use a flag. allDataFetched. Bind it with your HTML using *ngIf:

```
<div *ngFor="let col of questionCollection" *ngIf="allDataFetched">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">{{col.Text}}</button>
</div>
```

In component. You can initialise this boolean variable as false. When all data is loaded then you can set it to true.

```
//component file
  allDataFetched: boolean = false;
    ngOnInit() {
        this._service.getQuestions().subscribe(data => { 
            this.questionCollection = data; 
            this.allDataFetched = true; });
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can use `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` on the same element. And why would you need a separate `allDataFetched` property, when you can look to see if `questionCollection` has a value to know if the subscription data has come in?

Answer (score 4):

Angular provide a [`resolver`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard) for that. If you want to whole component will wait until the data, you should use `resolve`. If you want some data area in component not display before data, just use `ngIf` to control as above.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to use `*ngIf`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="questionCollection">
  <div> Other text here...... </div>
  <div *ngFor="let col of questionCollection">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">{{col.Text}}</button>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an async pipe, which will listen to the request observable. Its predefined in angular '| async'.